# Pass a bidimensional array and store as a class menber

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I have an C++ class with a bidimensional array of ints.

This member is setted by one method of the class.

```cpp
class MyClass {
  private:
    int values[][4];

  public:
    MyClass();
    void setValues(int values[][4]);
```

if I do this:

```cpp
MyClass::setValues(int values[][4]) {
  Serial.println(values[0][0]);
}
```

Everything works without erros. But if I do this:

```cpp
MyClass::setValues(int values[][4]) {
  this->values = values;
}
```

I got `invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` error.

I need this bidimensional away to use on others method of this class.

How can I save this as a class member?

Comment: `std::vector<int>` as a calculated 2-D vector, or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as a vector-of-vectors-of-ints.

Comment: This is an unsized array, so you can't put it in a `class` like that. It needs a fixed size. Use `std::vector` if available, or `new[]` if not.

Comment: Forget C-style arrays exist. Exclusively use `std::array` or `std::vector` in their place. Live a happier life.

Comment: [An example of  the calculated 2D vector Eljay's talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<int>> is not working... Do I need add some libary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with Vector.h from ArduinoIDE libiries.

But, I don`t use a Vector of Vectors...

Frist of all, I created a `struct`

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  unsigned long d;
  
  MyStruct(int a, int b, int c, unsigned long d) {
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    this->c = c;
    this->d = d;
  }
};
```

Then, change my method to `void set(Vector<MyStruct> steps);` and call this like that:

```cpp
  MyStruct steps[6] = {MyStruct(50, 0, 0, 100),
                      MyStruct(20, 0, 0, 100),
                      MyStruct(50, 0, 0, 100),
                      MyStruct(20, 0, 0, 100),
                      MyStruct(50, 0, 0, 100),
                      MyStruct(0, 0, 0, 500)
                     };
  Vector<MyStruct> vector(steps, 6);
  myClass.setSteps(vector);
```

It`s working now :D

Comment: Arduino is not a complete C++ compiler. Some responders don't realise this and suggest solutions like `std::vector` that work in regular C++ but not in Arduino.